# Cannot download R library from github

Tags: r, github, devtools

first of all I would like to point out that I dont program in R and thus my knowledge on this programming language in non-existent. However, I have to use a specific code written in R to generate some results. I am trying to install the Package assessEpidemicCurves, from https://github.com/jpmeagher/assessEpidemicCurves. I followed the reccomended steps

1. Install devtools: `install.packages("devtools")`
2. Install the package: `devtools::install_github("jpmeagher/assessEpidemicCurves")`

However, when I try to import the library in the code using `library(assessEpidemicCurves)` I get the following error message

```r
Error in library(assessEpidemicCurves) : 

  there is no package called ‘assessEpidemicCurves’
```

Could someone help me to get this to work? I am running this on Rstudio  with `R 4.2.0`, sorry if this not sufficient information but as i said before I dont know anything about R :( . Thank you in advance.

Comment: What prints in the R console after you run the `devtools::install_github("jpmeagher/assessEpidemicCurves")` command? Do you see errors or warnings?

Comment: I'm guessing you are seeing this error message: `Error: Failed to install 'assessEpidemicCurves' from GitHub: 
  Could not find tools necessary to compile a package`. Per the DESCRIPTION file you need a fair number of other R packages as well as a system file named GNU make. That system file would only be avaialble by default on a Linux machine, while in MacOS and Window you would need to install either Xcode or Rtools.

Comment: The information provided is insufficient to determine the cause of the failure to install the package. No response to request to update question. Voting to close.

Answer (score -1):

Try to update r and all the packages and use new version of R

i followed the same steps :

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("jpmeagher/assessEpidemicCurves")
library(assessEpidemicCurves)
```

and it worked well for me

Comment: Requirements ar listed in the DESCRIPTION file.